# jq command to replace specific words in json file

Tags: json, jq

Good evening all,
I am looking for a solution to replace specific words in a json file using jq command. The field I want to be changed is called "Stock" and if the value is "Add to cart" or just "add" I want this replaced with "In stock".

Would you guys mind to help me since I have zero knowledge in jq but I need to use it for my project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way you’ve formulated the question makes it sound as though it’s some kind of homework or assignment, so let’s assume you really are looking for help rather than an explicit answer.

First, it would make sense to learn about asking questions on stackoverflow.com; for that, the mcve page would be a good starting point. In your case, the points of clarification that would be helpful are whether the input is an object, and whether the relevant keys all occur within the top-most level object(s).

Second, in reading through the jq documentation, pay particular attention to the `to_entries`, `from-entries`, and `with_entries` filters.

Third, if you require a completely generic solution, search the web using these search terms:

```
(stackoverflow OR faq) jq def walk
```